# VBA unable to Activate graph

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am displaying a graph in a userform therefore I have to export the graph to jpg and load it back in. Sometimes the graph doesn't save to the file and after viewing this question [{link}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682041/exporting-charts-as-image-sometimes-generates-empty-files-excel-vba). I see the soplution is to activate the graph. But this creates an error "method activate of object _chart failed" How do I Activate the Graph?

```
Function Load_Chart(Area)
Dim Est As Worksheet
Dim CurrentChart As Chart

Set Est = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Estimate")
    Set CurrentChart = Est.Shapes("Estimate Chart").Chart
    CurrentChart.Activate
    CurrentChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Estimate").Range(Area)

CurrentChart.Export VBA.Environ("Temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "CurrentChart.jpg"

    Me.imgChart.Picture = LoadPicture(VBA.Environ("Temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "CurrentChart.jpg")

End Function
```

***EDIT***
I just noticed that if I locate the graph in the spreadsheet before I try to export it, it works correctly and I do not need the line `CurrentChart.Activate` I do not know if this is linked?

Comment: Untested, but activate that sheet before you try to activate the chart?

Comment: ```ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Estimate").Activate```
I used this in the form initialisation and still can't activate the graph

Comment: What does "I locate the graph in the spreadsheet" mean? What code are you using to "locate"?

Comment: Maybe just add a couple of `DoEvents` after the `SetSourceData` line, to give Excel a chance to catch up.  I've never seen a case where it was necessary to activate the chart before exporting it.

Comment: Before I export the graph I open the spreasheet in the background to the exact cell where the graph is located using ```Application.Goto Worksheets("Estimate").Range("CE4")```

Comment: Even with a 30 second wait after the `SetSourceData` it still fails to export the image, its as if the graph isn't loaded until you traverse to the cell, either manually or with a `Application.Goto`